# Pass object initialized via express middleware to next middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Below is my setup, I am trying to pass an object that is initialized in express middleware to a different middleware function. In my router, Invoke helper.getValues() and get an error that I cannot invoke function getValues of undefined

```
let helper; // no initial value

const getConfig = async () => {
    config = await service.getConfig(configName);
    helper = new Helper(config);    // Helper is correctly initialized here
};

// declare a new express app
let app = express();


app.use(async function (req, res, next) {
    try {        
        await getConfig(); // invoke the code that initializes my helper       
        next();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});


app.use('/path', MyRouter(helper)); // Pass helper to router - it's undefined in router code
```

My Router Constructor looks like this

```
function MyRouter(helper) {
   ...
   ... const values = helper.getValues();
}
```

What is the correct way to pass the helper that is created in getConfig to my router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it via `req` or `res` depending on your intent.

If the data relates to the request such as the requesting user's identity, the session attributes, geoIP or parsed request body then attach it to the `req` object:

If the data relates to response processing such as variables used by templates/views or requested response format then attach it to the `res` object.

Assuming you want to pass it via `req`:

```
req.helper = await getConfig();
```

Then to use it:

```
function router (req, res) {
    const values = req.helper.getValues();

    // ...
}
```